# Find and insert value in column based textfile

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

I have kind of an annoying problem. I have some old textfiles once exported from a retired financial system long since shut down. Some lines of the data are corrupt, so that values occur in the wrong column.

Example:

```
123     99999 
123     87675 
65453   62 
123     64534
```

The values in the first column should never consist of 5 numbers and the second column should always consist of 5 numbers.

So far I came up with a way to find the problematic lines:

```
cat tempfile | grep -n '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

I would like to find a way to find the row number of the problematic line, just as above:

```
65463     62
```

.... then insert "123" and a space or tab, to make it look like,

```
123     65463     62
```

How could this be done the least complicated way, preferably in Bash.

Regards
Paul

Comment: In the output there's no line number ¿you don't need it?

Comment: Or this would do? `sed -E 's/([0-9]{5})/123\t\1/' file`

Answer (score 0):

`awk` would suit well here

```
$ awk 'length($1)>3{$0 = "123\t" $0} 1' ip.txt
123     99999
123     87675
123     65453   62
123     64534
```

- `length($1)` gives you length of first field
- `$0 = "123\t" $0` will change the content of line as desired
- `1` idiomatic way to print content of `$0`

Comment: Thank you Sundeep. Your command did the job!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's/^[0-9]{5}/123\t&/' yourfile
```

Makes use of `&` which is a special character to `sed`, representing the entire matched string.

Using `sed -r` enables extended regex, specifically the `{ }` in this example.

Comment: When you post, add a little explanation and tell OP what is different from other posts made. In this case the use of `&`.